# TS2511: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class 'Validator'

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I'm new to TypeScript.

How come I get this error message?

I don't intend to initialize abstract class. 
I intend to initialize a concrete class that is IsEmptyValidator in validatorMap dictionary.

> TS2511: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class 'Validator'

```
interface Dictionary<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}

abstract class Validator {
    constructor() {
        console.log("super");
    }
}

class IsEmptyValidator extends Validator {
    public validate() {}

    constructor(){
        super();
        console.log("isEmpty");
    }
}

class ValidatorFactory {
    private validatorMap: Dictionary<Validator> = {
        "isEmpty": IsEmptyValidator
    };

    constructor() { }

    public create(validatorType: string) {
        let validatorToCreate: Validator = new this.validatorMap[validatorType];

        return validatorToCreate;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might enjoy http://formstate.github.io/ 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your dictionary doesn't have instances `Validator` but classes of it, so you should do this:

```
type ValidatorConstructor = {
    new (): Validator;
}

class ValidatorFactory {
    private validatorMap: Dictionary<ValidatorConstructor> = {
        "isEmpty": IsEmptyValidator
    };

    constructor() {}

    public create(validatorType: string) {
        let validatorToCreate: Validator = new this.validatorMap[validatorType]();

        return validatorToCreate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than create a new answer, you'll also need to keep the dictionary you have, and you may want to add an abstract `validate()` method in your base class, and override it in your `IsEmptyValidator` instead. Then you can call `validate()` from any instance of a derived `Validator`. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mariocatch/cd086fd868625737a86b5c8f6691d86f)

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't understand "type ValidatorConstructor = {
    new (): Validator;
}" but I look it up.

Comment: Read about it here: [Difference between the static and instance sides of classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes)

Comment: Thank you for the link!!